# How get page number for subject by id?

Tags: php, laravel

This code gets list of products for current page:

```
Product::paginate( 10 );
```

For example the page number `4` includes `Product` with `id=100`.

Can I get the number of page `4` if I only know Product id `100`?

Comment: `$_REQUEST['page']` use this

Answer (score 1):

Use `getCollection()` to get the datas from page, and get the index that you want:

```php
$products = Product::paginate( 10 );
$products->getCollection()->where('id', 100)->keys()->first();
```